# Is there any way to know that client has downloaded file completely?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have one large file.

I want to do the following
 1) want to upload it to server
 2) I want to delete file automatically from the server once user has downloaded it successfully.

Is there any way to know that client has finished its download ?

Comment: What's your server technology?

Comment: I have the feeling that looking at the server logs is the only way to be sure.

Comment: I would suggest using a script to proxy the download.  When the script is done, the file is obviously done, so it can be removed.  Something like: `readfile($file); unlink($file);`

Comment: It's going to be difficult to discern between "the server has sent the file to the client" and "the user is now in possession of the file."

Comment: Also, you should consider the fact that the user could simply close the browser while downloading, in which case the file was not downloaded.

Comment: Assuming what you want to know is that the browser has finished downloading the file, one way to handle that would be to have, in the success handler for the `$.ajax()` call which (I assume) you're using to download the file, another call to `$.ajax()` which communicates with a handler on the server to let it know the download has finished. Since the first Ajax call's success handler won't be fired until (and unless) the transfer finishes and the connection is closed in good order, this should avoid concerns about, e.g., the file being deleted if the user prematurely stops the download.

Comment: You could try something like this: detect when the download has started, estimate by the size of the file how long it would take to download in a worst case scenario, and delete it a couple of seconds after that estimate. It's hacky, and not exactly what you're looking for, but it might just work for you.

Comment: @JoeEnos : I am using PHP as a server technology

Answer (score 0):

If your server has cron jobs, then you could set up one of those to run a PHP script outside of the public web directory at a "safe" increment (a time at which they've either downloaded the file or won't be getting it). Every time the script runs, delete files which have already been marked, and mark all remaining files. Might look something like this but with real code:

```
<?php
// File description: scheduled by cron jobs to run every 12 hours

// Unlink all the marked files

// Mark all files in directory
```

You could store the name of marked files in a text document (also outside of your public web directory) for example. This way users have at least that long to download the file.